# A question about scanf_s and pointer array

Tags: c

occer an error in scanf_s.
I wrote `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` instead of `scanf_s`, but it doesn't work.
In my opinion, `scanf_s` does not receive two arguments.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 80

void mystery1(char* s1, const char* s2);

int main(void)
{
    char string1[SIZE];
    char string2[SIZE];

    puts("Enter two strings: ");
    scanf_s("%79s%79s", string1, string2);  // Error
    mystery1(string1, string2);
    printf("%s", string1);
}

void mystery1(char* s1, const char* s2)
{
    
    while (*s1 !='\0')
    {
        ++s1;
    }
    for (; *s1 = *s2; ++s1, ++s2)
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

**Input**

> helloworld

Comment: You should check return values of `scanf` and similar functions.

Comment: On a side note: Your title is misleading. There is no pointer array involved in your code. Just an array. A pointer array is normally read as "array of pointers" which you don't have.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm just a college student just starting to learn c language, so there are a lot of inexperienced
Thanks for pointing out the title, this is my first question on stackoverflow, so it's not easy. I tried to write hello world, but the program ends without output. I know that string1 and string2 are the addresses of the first values ​​of the array, respectively.

Comment: Incidentally, this code is the code in the textbook, so I'm really puzzled too.

Comment: `scanf_s` is a function from a Microsoft library, not the Standard Library. It's similar to the standard `scanf` but not identical.

Comment: Always enable the compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments you are using is scanf function `scanf("%79s%79s", string1, string2);`.
The scanf_s function is used like this:

```
scanf_s("%79s%79s", string1, 80, string2, 80)
```

I don't know what this function `void mystery1(char* s1, const char* s2)` does? but in the for loop you have to use "==" instead of "="

Comment: Thanks so much for letting me know, I solved it thanks to you `scanf("%79s%79s", string1, 80, string2, 80);` After writing this, the program is running! This program is a program that combines two strings into one sentence! Thanks again for letting me know! have a good evening :)

Comment: @HwangSoohyeon the code in your comment is incorrect. The answer shows how to use `scanf` and `scanf_s`. The `scanf_s` *isn't* a "drop-in safe replacement" for `scanf` despite the similarity in their names.